# Is there any way to call useQuery with dynamic variables?

Tags: graphql, react-hooks, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have an array which contains multiples timestamps. That array dynamically creating by some parameters. I want to call useQuery with these timestamps. I am looking for a way to call with these dynamically created timestamps to useQuery in apollo.

Here my attempt:

```
const useDynamicQuery = (date, partnerBranchId) => {
  const response = useQuery(VERTICAL_TIMELINE, {
    variables: { date, partnerBranchId }
  })
  return [response]
}

const results = dynamicArrayContainsTimestamps.map(date => useDynamicQuery(date, 13))
```

Comment: why not to render list of items/components with useQuery inside?

Comment: I just wonder if it is possible. But now I found a package which is apollo-fetch. I have achieved what I want with this package. By the way this package is deprecated, we should use apollo-link instead.